# Delete the match id using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

```js
let deleteArray = ["userSystem","accessFile","adminLog"];

var userData={
profile:[
{
 sys:{
   system:{
   log:"true"
  },
  id:"userSystem",
  display:true
  },
  fname:"john",
  lname:"andrew"
  },
{
 sys:{
   system:{
   log:"true"
  },
  id:"adminFile",
  display:true
  },
  fname:"jerry",
  lname:"tom"
  },
{
 sys:{
   system:{
   log:"true"
  },
  id:"accessFile",
  display:true
  },
  fname:"james",
  lname:"bond"
  },
{
 sys:{
   system:{
   log:"true"
  },
  id:"userPublic",
  display:true
  },
  fname:"john",
  lname:"Cena"
  }]
,
admin:[
{
 meta:{
  log:true,
  id:"adminLog"
 },
 value:"Accessable"
},
{
 meta:{
  log:true,
  id:"adminPanel"
 },
 value:"Accessable"
},
]
}


deleteArray.map(deleteId=>{
 userData = userData.profile.map(data=>{
   if(data.sys.id===deleteId){
   delete data[deleteId];
  }
 });
 userData = userData.admin.map(data=>{
   if(data.meta.id===deleteId){
   delete data[deleteId];
  }
 });
  console.log(userData);
});
```

I am trying to delete the match id which is present inside the deleteArray with the userData. The match id is getting delete inside the map but when I am trying to console It showing me whole data again I want to save the modified data in which the json is not present

as my expected value is like this after the deleted match id and I want to store same like this in JSON file but I dont know where I am doing something wrong

### Expected Value

```
{
  "profile": [
    {
      "sys": {
        "system": {
          "log": "true"
        },
        "id": "adminFile",
        "display": true
      },
      "fname": "jerry",
      "lname": "tom"
    },
    {
      "sys": {
        "system": {
          "log": "true"
        },
        "id": "userPublic",
        "display": true
      },
      "fname": "john",
      "lname": "Cena"
    }
  ],
  "admin": [
    {
      "meta": {
        "log": true,
        "id": "adminPanel"
      },
      "value": "Accessable"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `map()` does **not** change the original array. Either you can reassign `userData = userData.map(...)` or use mutable operations like [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: I tried to reassign but its not working throwing an error @cSharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your userData using filter & Array.Every as

```
   const profileFilter = userData.profile.filter((data) =>
      // returns true only if it doesn't in the deleteArray
      deleteArray.every((key) => data.sys.id !== key)
    );
    const adminFilter = userData.admin.filter((data) =>
      deleteArray.every((key) => data.meta.id !== key)
    );
    const updatedUserData = {
      profile: [...profileFilter],
      admin: [...adminFilter],
    };
    console.log(updatedUserData);
```